# Register a new user in ejabberd using Erlang

Tags: erlang, xmpp, ejabberd

I am using erlang 17, ejabberd 14.07. I am trying to create chat application, For that I have to create user for ejabberd using Erlang. I have search but nothing found useful. There are three ways to do registration as far I have explored.

1. Using command line
2. From localhost
3. Using other api

Is there any method in ejabberd which help me to register new user? I am new in Erlang and ejabberd so it becomes useful to me if you describe step if any configuration required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean that you want to call an Erlang function to create a user?  You can use `ejabberd_auth:try_register` for that:

```
ejabberd_auth:try_register(<<"username">>, <<"example.com">>, <<"secret_password">>).
```

Comment: Can you suggest me link from where you have find this Method?

Comment: I found it by digging around in `ejabberd_admin.erl`. It contains the code for everything that can be done using the command line tool, so it's usually a good way to find how to do something programmatically.

Comment: Thanks, But Structure of try_register method is old not new one as you suggest. How you recognize it?

Comment: Guys this is not helping in any way.... Please share tips/tricks to register a user with ejabbered using erlang application... 

The answer which you gave is not work as it is ** exception error: undefined function ejabberd_auth:try_register/3

Comment: Hi @legoscia. [I am unable to use `ejabberd_auth` in my **helloworld** project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49220369/i-am-unable-to-use-ejabberd-auth-in-my-helloworld-project). Could you please help. I've trying to make it work for days now. I would very much appreciate any help in any way. I'm trying to write a messaging application in Erlang and Ejabberd.

Comment: Hi @KJ_kaka. I have the same problem you had : "`** exception error: undefined function ejabberd_auth:try_register/3`". [I am unable to use ejabberd_auth in my helloworld project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49220369/i-am-unable-to-use-ejabberd-auth-in-my-helloworld-project). Could you please help. I've trying to make it work for days now. I would very much appreciate any help in any way. I'm trying to write a messaging application in Erlang and Ejabberd using IntelliJ.

Comment: Hi @legoscia. I have have a persistent problem whenever I try to write an Ejabberd application in Erlang : "`** exception error: undefined function ejabberd_auth:try_register/3`". I have posted it here in the **QUESTION :** [I am unable to use ejabberd_auth in my helloworld project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49220369/i-am-unable-to-use-ejabberd-auth-in-my-helloworld-project). Could you please help. I've trying to make it work for days now. I would very much appreciate any help in any way. I'm trying to write a messaging application in Erlang and Ejabberd using IntelliJ.