# How to register a new user in ejabberd

Tags: java, android, c++, erlang, ejabberd

From [egoscia's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25546477/3663765) on the question [Register a new user in ejabberd using Erlang](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25541829/3663765), he says in the accepted answer that you can add a new user using:

```
ejabberd_auth:try_register(<<"username">>, <<"example.com">>, <<"secret_password">>).
```

I tried using this in erlang, but I get the error:

```
** exception error: undefined function ejabberd_auth:try_register/3
```

This is a snippet of  how I go about it:

```
-import(ejabberd_auth, [try_register/3]).

start() ->
  io:fwrite("Hello World!\nThis is Sound\n"),

  % Chat
  ejabberd_auth:try_register(<<"username">>, <<"example.com">>, <<"secret_password">>).
```

How should I go about it erlang? Java/  Android/ C++/ Qt suggestions also welcome.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: you can use ejabberd's XMLRPC for calling ejabberd internal commands using other language (i have implemented using PHP for registering user and add roster). check this link it explains xmlrpc, https://www.ejabberd.im/ejabberd_xmlrpc

Answer (score 1):

> ** exception error: undefined function ejabberd_auth:try_register/3

Oh, that code works for me using ejabberd 18.03. I start ejabberd in live mode, so I have access to the erlang shell, and I can run correctly:

```
$ ejabberdctl live
...
(ejabberd@localhost)2> ejabberd_auth:try_register(<<"user6">>, <<"localhost">>, <<"somepass">>).
ok
```

Maybe you are using an old ejabberd version that doesn't still export ejabberd_auth:try_register/3  ?